# Как сделать ссылкам время жизни до клика и другой на 12 часов?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Как сделать срок жизни ссылки 12 часов и другой на 1 клик? с помощью чего?php,js?

Comment: @Анатолийй, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: php На JS такое глупо делать

Comment: @naym а если на php то через что?

Comment: > через что?

@Анатолийй, через одно место, которое называется cookie. Познакомится с ними, можно уже через другое место - [документация][1]. ))

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё делается на php.
Если Вам требуется создать временную (срок жизни 12 часов) ссылку, то достаточно условия проверки прошедшего времени с времени создания ссылки. Условно храним данные (время и данные которые требуется отдать) в БД.
В .thaccess создаём правило по которому будут определятся заходы по временным ссылкам

```
RewriteRule ^download/(A-Za-z0-9)$ index.php?download=1&param=$1 [L]
```

В index.php перехватываем наличие GET переменных download (если == 1) и значение param( это данные идентифицирующие нашу временную ссылку).
При создании временной ссылки заводим в БД строку с данными по ссылке ( время создания[curent_timestamp],[ данные для отдачи по ссылке],[ уникальный идентификатор ссылки, то что будет указано в $_GET['param']]).

```
При заходе на страницу формата http://site.com/download/aJlo39JDSK09
```

После всех проверок можно отправлять запрос в БД для проверки наличия записи с уникальным индентификатором == aJlo39JDSK09.
Если такой идентификатор существует, отнимаем от текущего времени время создания ссылки. Если разница меньше 12 часов, отдаём нужную информацию [данные для отдачи по ссылке] и удаляем запись из таблицы

```
delete from `table` where uniqID = 'aJlo39JDSK09'`.
```

Если запись не существует то выводим шаблон что `файл`, `запись`, `информация` итд по данной ссылке не найдена. Если разница во времени больше 12 часов то удаляем запись из БД и выводим сообщение что время ссылки истекло.
Как то так. Код писать лень, да и исходной информации мало (ТЗ слабенькое и неконкретное). Но по алгоритму можно сделать :-).

ЗЫ звиняйте писал пьяный.